# SQL Query to find Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

I have table structure as below:

```
STOCKNO  QTY    OP
 12345   1.00   +
 12345   25.00  -
 12345   1.00   -
 12345   10.00  +
 123456  10.00  +
 123456  1.00   -
```

I want to get the actual qty balance of each stockno by +, -

```
+ (i.e. Purchase Qty)
- (i.e. Sales Qty)
```

But for above I am getting total purchase qty & sales qty using below query:

```
 SELECT STOCKNO, SUM(QTY) as QTY, OP
 FROM DT
 GROUP BY STOCKNO, OP
```

AND I want to get the actual closing qty record of each stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT STOCKNO,
       SUM(case when OP = '-' then -QTY else QTY end) as BALANCE
FROM DT 
GROUP BY STOCKNO
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a case inside the sum

```
select STOCKNO, sum(case when OP = '+' then 1 else -1 end * QTY) as StockLevel
from DT
group by STOCKNO
```

Answer (score 0):

Another options (just for fun) is to concat() the OP and Qty

**Example**

```
Select STOCKNO
      ,Ttl = sum(convert(decimal(10,2),concat(OP,QTY)))
 from YourTable
 Group By STOCKNO
```

**Returns**

```
STOCKNO Ttl
12345   -15.00
123456  9.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select STOCKNO,OP, sum(QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY STOCKNO,OP) as StockLevel
from DT
```